# python scraping cs 109 data science home work 1 assitance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, data-science

I have been working through the online material of CS 109 homework 1 and am currently stuck on problem 2, having trouble parsing the data from the soup object into a pandas `dataframe`, any help would be greatly appreciated:

**Problem**

Even though `get_poll_xml` pulls data from the web into Python, it does so as a block of text. This still isn't very useful. Use the web module in pattern to parse this text, and extract data into a pandas `DataFrame`.

**Hints**

You might want create python lists for each column in the XML. Then, to turn these lists into a `DataFrame`, run

```
pd.DataFrame({'column_label_1': list_1, 'column_label_2':list_2, ...})
```

use the pandas function pd.to_datetime to convert strings into dates

```
"""

Function
---------
rcp_poll_data

Extract poll information from an XML string, and convert to a DataFrame

Parameters
----------
xml : str
    A string, containing the XML data from a page like 
    get_poll_xml(1044)

Returns
-------
A pandas DataFrame with the following columns:
    date: The date for each entry
    title_n: The data value for the gid=n graph (take the column name from the `title` tag)

This DataFrame should be sorted by date

Example
-------
Consider the following simple xml page:

<chart>
<series>
<value xid="0">1/27/2009</value>
<value xid="1">1/28/2009</value>
</series>
<graphs>
<graph gid="1" color="#000000" balloon_color="#000000" title="Approve">
<value xid="0">63.3</value>
<value xid="1">63.3</value>
</graph>
<graph gid="2" color="#FF0000" balloon_color="#FF0000" title="Disapprove">
<value xid="0">20.0</value>
<value xid="1">20.0</value>
</graph>
</graphs>
</chart>

Given this string, rcp_poll_data should return
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['1/27/2009', '1/28/2009']), 
                       'Approve': [63.3, 63.3], 'Disapprove': [20.0, 20.0]})
```

here is the model answer :

```
def rcp_poll_data(xml): 
result = {}

dom = web.DOM(xml)

dates = dom.by_tag('series')[0]    
dates = {n.attributes['xid']: str(n.content) for n in dates.by_tag('value')}

#print dates

keys = dates.keys()

#print keys

result['date'] = pd.to_datetime([dates[k] for k in keys])



for graph in dom.by_tag('graph'):
    name = graph.attributes['title']
    data = {n.attributes['xid']: float(n.content) 
            if n.content else np.nan for n in graph.by_tag('value')}

    print data

    result[name] = [data[k] for k in keys]

result = pd.DataFrame(result)    
result = result.sort(columns=['date'])

return result
```

here is my answer:

```
def rcp_poll_data(xml):

#first lets get a beautifulsoup object so that we can manipulate the data
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')

#test to see that our soup object is working..
print type(soup)
print soup.prettify()

#declare the dictionary to hold all the different columns (that will eventually be changed to a dataframe)
finalResult = {}


#working dictionary version
my_date_dict = {series.attrs["xid"]: series.get_text() for series in soup.find("series").find_all("value") if soup.value.get_text()}

#convert the dictionary into a pandas dataframe. But first we need the keys to access each element

keys = my_date_dict.keys()

#then interate through each item in the dictionary to insert it into the dataframe using the appropriate key

finalResult['date'] = pd.to_datetime([my_date_dict[k] for k in keys])


for item in soup.find_all("graph"):
    print "found a graph tag!"
    print"creating a dict entry..."

    name = item.attrs["title"]

    tempdict = {}    

    tempdict = {item.value.attrs["xid"]: test.get_text() for test in soup.find("graph").find_all("value") if soup.value.get_text()}

    print tempdict

    finalResult[name] = [tempdict[k] for k in keys]

return result
```

Comment: I'd rename the title of your question as something other than "homework help", both for future people who might want to know the answer and for your own sake. Just describe the problem :)

Comment: *What* is wrong with your answer? Please see how to create a [mcve]